# How to secure form from spam bot

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

In my Magento shop, i have a form, witch send the information via email to me, and recently there have ben a lot of spam from that form (70 since yesterday).

Is it posible, to get a secure form in magento, witout using CAPTHA? :)

Comment: This answer might be helpful to you. --> http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103808/how-can-i-protect-my-magento-site-from-spam/103836#103836

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem and I solved it by installing this extension from the magento-hackaton: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/HoneySpam

> This Magento Extension adds a field which is hidden with JavaScript to
>   the Customer Register and the Product Review Form which looks like the
>   URL Field of a Wordpress Comment Form. If this field gets filled and
>   the Form is send, there appears a error message and nothing will be
>   saved.
>
> There is also a check if this form is too fast transmitted, a human
>   normally takes a couple of Seconds or more.
>
> You can enable and disable the functionalities or set the time how
>   long it should take to transmit this forms in the Magento Admin
>   Backend.
>
> Freshly added: Regex-checking on all input-fields to determine a loose
>   index for spam-level. It is not the most accurate thing at all, but it
>   may prevent the low-end spam ("broadband spam"). You also can
>   enable/disable this feature in the backend and set a maximum spam
>   index trust level.

This is how I added it to my form:

On my form .phtml file I added this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('contacts.form.fields.before') ?>
```

This will add the extra field declared in  app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/honeyspam.xml:

```
<default>
    <update handle="honeypot"/>
    <reference name="footer_newsletter">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="contacts.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
            <block type="hackathon_honeyspam/honeypot" name="honeyspam.honeypot"
                   template="hackathon/honeyspam/honeypot.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>

<contacts_index_index>
    <update handle="honeypot"/>
    <reference name="contactForm">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="contacts.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
            <block type="hackathon_honeyspam/honeypot" name="honeyspam.honeypot"
                   template="hackathon/honeyspam/honeypot.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

Comment: It's a custom form, and i can se that extension is only good for magentomade forms

Comment: not really, is not a custom form it adds an extra field to the forms you want, so you can use this extension for any form you want. You just need to include the js file there and that is it.

Comment: I approve of this extension. I used it and it has done wonders. It won't get you 100% spam free, but it does a wonderful job with a minimum effort.

Comment: my form is on my productpage, how do i include the js files there? its the view.phtml file.

Comment: got @Marius  approval. now you must install extension.

Comment: @PatrickKnudsen can you post this into a separate question and add more details? Also consider approving my answer if it helped you.

Comment: @lloiacono will approve your answer when my problem is solved :) and so far no luck

Answer (score 0):

The added code for the newsletter is incorrect. I have half the correct code, problem remains that you can only make one form hidden at a time with document.observe code. We have 2 newsletter boxes and the standard review/contact forms and that doesn't work.

This is the correct part for the default magento install footer newsletter though.

```
    <default>
    <update handle="honeypot"/>
    <reference name="footer.newsletter">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="newsletter.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
            <block type="hackathon_honeyspam/honeypot" name="honeyspam.honeypot"
                   template="hackathon/honeyspam/honeypot.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Anybody the complete solution?

Comment: I  just a bit confuss her, should I add the above code to newsletter.xml in app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout? How can I see it is corrected installed?