# Manage customer from admin panel?

Tags: magento1.9.3.1

Today, i login into admin panel & Go into customer->manage customer.
The grid contain lists of customer but customer name column contain URL & in different language instead of english.

Please see the below image. Is this bug ??
If yes, ten how to solve this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have been "hacked" :D (Russians are too good for that ) . Check the suggested solutions from DependencyHell [LINK](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233368/prevent-spam-account-registration/240716#240716)

As first of the options i will suggest

```
 Solution 4: Captcha (Magento or Google)
```

The russians bots have bypassed your registration form.

Comment: "Hacked" is a bit misleading - it just looks like the signup endpoint has been spammed programmatically.

Comment: yeah i know @user7290573 , added "" :D

Comment: @yigen, this site (https://www.linguee.com/) is continuously hitting  some URL of our site.. i have checked through apache access.log.  How to block this  ?

Comment: @Pankaj i dont think the website is causing it , but anyway ,grab from logs the IP that are hitting and block them , tell your Network Support to block them,

Comment: https://www.linguee.com/bot , thanks @YIgen,  i have blocked bot url of linguee

Comment: @Pankaj ok great.