# Magento 2.2.6 How to Prevent Spam Account Registration

Tags: magento2, customer-account, recaptcha

I tried to use the solution 6 from here, but not exactly sure how to do it.

> [Prevent Spam Account Registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233368/prevent-spam-account-registration/240716#240716)
>   Solution 6: Update fields limitation rules from database : directly in
>   the customer_eav_attribute table, update rows with attribute_id=5
>   [firstname] and attribute_id=7 [lastname] and replace 255 by 25 :

In my magento 2.2.6 version, the attribute_id=5 and 7 has

> validate_rules="{"max_text_length":225,"min_text_length":1}"

and also

> input_filter="trim"

I tried to change them to

> validate_rules ="{"max_text_length":25,"min_text_length":1}"

and

> input_filter =""

but i'm still getting a lot of Russian spam account registration.

Comment: spam registration is coming from unprotected API access. see my answer below. you can generate accounts registration all day long with customized data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2 extension for blocking spam creating new customer accounts

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-google-recaptcha

https://github.com/samsteele/spam-registration-blocker

https://github.com/arcmedia/mage2-customer-honeypot

Magento 2 extension for blocking (RUSSIAN) spam bots creating new customer accounts

https://github.com/Kreativsoehne/magento-2-simple-antispam

Comment: i installed the mageplaza google recaptcha extension yesterday, have not get any new russian spam signup for a day now, i'll pick this one as an answer. thanks.

Comment: glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

in magento 2.3.1 you can simply create user with direct API access, using POSTMAN request with `Content-Type:application/json`
and this `raw` body:

```
{
    "customer": {
        "email": "jdoe@example.com",
        "firstname": "Jane",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "addresses": [
            {
                "defaultShipping": true,
                "defaultBilling": true,
                "firstname": "Jane",
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "region": {
                    "regionCode": "NY",
                    "region": "New York",
                    "regionId": 43
                },
                "postcode": "10755",
                "street": [
                    "123 Oak Ave"
                ],
                "city": "Purchase",
                "telephone": "512-555-1111",
                "countryId": "US"
            }
        ]
    },
    "password": "Password1"
}
```

> response:

```
{
    "id": 22,
    "group_id": 1,
    "default_billing": "16",
    "default_shipping": "16",
    "created_at": "2019-06-09 11:48:19",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-09 11:48:19",
    "created_in": "Default Store View",
    "email": "jdoe@example.com",
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "store_id": 1,
    "website_id": 1,
    "addresses": [
        {
            "id": 16,
            "customer_id": 22,
            "region": {
                "region_code": "NY",
                "region": "New York",
                "region_id": 43
            },
            "region_id": 43,
            "country_id": "US",
            "street": [
                "123 Oak Ave"
            ],
            "telephone": "512-555-1111",
            "postcode": "10755",
            "city": "Purchase",
            "firstname": "Jane",
            "lastname": "Doe",
            "default_shipping": true,
            "default_billing": true
        }
    ],
    "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
        "is_subscribed": false
    }
}
```

To block Api user creation add below line at robots.txt

```
## web Api block if no need
Disallow:rest/default/V1/customers
Disallow:rest/*
```

Comment: Is API access on by default?  Do you not need an API user and / or role configured? Or is this on by default too?

Comment: magento 2 api is always open, some parts required access token, but mostly not.

Comment: I'm checking for creating a customer in the docs. Found this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-customer.html but that says you need token. Can you create customer without token? I'm trying to figure out whether we need to start locking down api. Also found this. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/anonymous-api-security.html. that would suggest yes it is open. But as you say a lot of stuff is open. That has surprised me.

Comment: wow. how do i lock down the create account api in this case?

Comment: you can deny access by IP or create some security rule, to check access with some logic

Comment: @MagenX any update on how to exactly accomplish the blocking without breaking magento functionality? Magento documentation says "The following APIs remain accessible to anonymous users. Most of these must remain accessible to support the checkout and add-to-cart Ajax functionalities." https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/anonymous-api-security.html

Answer (score 0):

Enable Captcha From

> Admin -> Store -> Configuration - > Customer -> Customer Configuration
>   - > Captcha , Choose Create User

option

Comment: I already enable the magento reCAPTCHA but they're bypassing it. thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting up more strict rules for captcha from admin, or try with third party google recaptcha