# How to block few email domains to register to our shop (spam problem)

Tags: magento-1.9, registration

Our shop got new fake customers every day and almost all of them uses hotmails.com or rumbler.com email addresses. There is no real customer that uses these email domains so easiest solution could be not to accept these domains in register process. But how to do that? Any ideas?

We already use magento captcha, but that does not not help at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you block them on server level by IP?

Comment: In this case the easiest way is to make your website go trough Cloudflare and there's an option there to block IPs.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How do I know what is the IP of registered customer? They are not listed under ONLINE-CUSTOMERS.

Comment: you probably have access to access.log file of your web server apache/nginx just look at the time when the customer registered and see who accessed that url path.

Comment: Blocking IP will only help for short time and they will use another IP Range. Have a look at this question. There are also answers for oyu: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233368/prevent-spam-account-registration

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answers. There are also some solutions: [Prevent Spam Account Registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233368/prevent-spam-account-registration) like a honeypot or other stuff.