# Blocking .ru Bots

Tags: email, customer-account, robots.txt

I've been getting a number of bots with an email that ends with .ru - I was hoping to stop them from creating customer accounts on our system.

I've seen a few SQL functions that will remove existing accounts from the database. I was wondering if there is any way to block .ru emails from creating an account to begin with? I haven't seen any suggestions or code for that.

Thanks Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a ton of problems with this as well. Mine started more as bots using me as a spamming method.
When I added the database field restrictions (Method 6 in the link below) it drastically reduced the number of .ru addresses since they would often not meet the field requirements.
This reduced it enough I just manually remove the ones that get through from time to time.

From my research the only full proof method is block all IPs from the originating regions.
I don't get enough to mess with it to much beyond the changes I made, but I have been keeping an eye on it.
Here is the link to the thread: [Prevent Spam Account Registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233368/prevent-spam-account-registration)
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I'll try these. I like being able to stop the spam before it actually is stored in the database.